# linked list is only storing the last element

Tags: c, linked-list, dynamic-memory-allocation, singly-linked-list

My linked list seems to only store the last element that I entered. In other words, if I add 3 cars and try to print list->head->manufaturer then I will get the last car I entered. The same goes for if I try and print list->head->next-> manufacturer I will get the last element I entered.

Additionally and more interestingly is that the print statement

```
  printf("the new node in begining func is %s\n", list->head->data->manufacturer);
```

seems to have the next element before I insert it into the linked list.

here are my structs

```
  typedef struct Node_car{
    Car *data;
    struct Node_car *next;
}Node;

struct LinkedCarList_s{
    Node *head;
    Node *tail;
};
```

here is my add function.

```
LinkedCarList carListCreate(){
    LinkedCarList new;
    new=(malloc(sizeof(LinkedCarList)));
    if(new==NULL) return 0;
    new->head = NULL;
    new->tail = NULL;
    return new;
}

int addNewNode(LinkedCarList list, Car *c){
if(list->head==NULL && list->tail==NULL){
    Node *newNode;
    newNode = (malloc(sizeof(Node)));
    newNode->data = c;
    newNode->next = NULL;
    list->head = newNode;
    list->tail = newNode;
    
    printf("in  if part add new func i added%s\n",newNode->data->manufacturer);
    return 1;
    
}
else{
    printf("the new node in begining func is %s\n", list->head->data->manufacturer);
    Node *newNode;
    newNode = (Node*)(malloc(sizeof(Node)));
    if(!newNode) return 0;
    newNode->data = c;
    newNode->next =list->head;
    
    list->head->next = newNode;
    printf("the new node in func is %s\n", list->head->data->manufacturer);
    printf("the new node as a newNOde is %s\n",newNode->data->manufacturer);
    printf("the new nodein func using next as a newNOde is %s\n",list->head->next->data->manufacturer);
    
}
return 1;
```

}

I call the function like this:

```
LinkedCarList lcarList;
lcarList =carListCreate();


addNewCar(lcarList);
```

Comment: Don't cast the value returned by `malloc()`.

Answer (score 1):

The memory allocation in the function `carListCreate`

```
new=(malloc(sizeof(LinkedCarList)));
```

is incorrect. You are allocating memory for a pointer.

You need to write

```
new = malloc( sizeof( *new ) );
```

And in the function `addNewNode` instead of this statement

```
list->head->next = newNode;
```

you need to write

```
list->head = newNode;
```

These statements

```
printf("the new node in func is %s\n", list->head->data->manufacturer);
printf("the new node as a newNOde is %s\n",newNode->data->manufacturer);
```

will output the same data because `head` and `newNode` after the above assignment point to the same node of the list.

And this statement

```
printf("the new nodein func using next as a newNOde is %s\n",list->head->next->data->manufacturer);
```

can invoke undefined behavior if the list contains only one node. So remove it.

Also check whether you are always passing a pointer to the same object of the type Car to the function. If so then you need to make a copy of the object pointed to by the pointer c. For example

```
newNode->data = malloc( sizeof( Car ) );
*newNode->data = *c;
```

And this call of the function `addNewCar`

```
addNewCar(lcarList);
```

is incorrect because the function expects two arguments

```
int addNewNode(LinkedCarList list, Car *c){
```

Comment: @qua You are mistaken. This works. What is not working is your code that you did not show.

Comment: Here is how I create a new linked list structre:
LinkedCarList carListCreate(){
    LinkedCarList new;
    new=(malloc(sizeof(LinkedCarList)));
    if(new==NULL) return 0;
    new->head = NULL;
    new->tail = NULL;
    return new;
}

Comment: @qua This memory allocation new=(malloc(sizeof(LinkedCarList))); is incorrect. You need to write new = malloc( sizeof( *new ) );

Comment: It is still not placing the elements. why should I allocate the memory using *new rather than the size of the structure which is LinkeCarList?

Comment: @qua LinkedCarList is not a structure. Otherwise you nay not write new=(malloc(sizeof(LinkedCarList))); because new must be a pointer. So it seems LinkedCarList is an alias for a pointer.

Comment: I am still receiving the same elements for all of the nodes (the last element).

Comment: The memory allocation was not the issue but the pointer was the issue. This is what solved my problem *newNode->data = *c;
Can you please explain what is going on here?

Comment: @qua As you did not show structure declarations then is seems the data member data has the type Car instead of Car *. But in any case the compiler should issue a message about this statement. You need to read all messages of the compiler.

Comment: I posted my structs above

Comment: @qua In this case the statement *newNode->data = *c; is an invalid statement.

Comment: that statement is what seemed to get the program working properly though.

Comment: @qua One more reread my answer. The pointer data is not initialized and does not point to a valid object.  You need to allocate dynamically memory at first and only after that to use the statement as it is written in my answer.